# Trigger jquery doesn't lau

Tags: jquery, triggers

I would like to launch a trigger on my select, but it seems that nothing is working :

This is my select :

```
<select id="sel_annee">
        <option value="<?php echo (date('Y')-1); ?>"><?php echo (date('Y')-1); ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo date('Y'); ?>" selected='selected'><?php echo date('Y'); ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo (date('Y')+1); ?>"><?php echo date('Y')+1; ?></option>
    </select>
```

this is my trigger :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

           $('#sel_annee').trigger("change");
```

and this is the function

```
$('#sel_annee').change(function()
           {
              alert("here");            
              $('.month').hide();
              $('.month:first').show();
              $('.months a:first').addClass('active');

                          $.ajax({
                             type: 'post',
                             url: 'changer_annee.php',
                             data:
                             {
                                year:$('#sel_annee').val()
                             },
                             dataType: 'text',

                             success: function(retour_php)
                             {
                                $('#month1').html('');         
                                //console.log(retour_php);
                                var arr = retour_php.split('#');

                                //console.log(retour_php);

                               for(i= 1; i<=12;i++)
                               {
                                  $('#month'+i).html(arr[i-1]);
                                  //console.log($('#month'+i));
                                  //console.log(arr[i]);
                               }

                               //$('.month').hide();
                               $('.month:first').show();
                               $('.months a').removeClass('active');
                               $('.months a:first').addClass('active');
                               //$('.months a:first').addClass('active');


                             },
                             error: function(retour_php)
                             {
                                alert("pas ok");
                                alert(retour_php);
                             }

                          }
                          );
           });
```

This alert doesn't work :

```
$('#sel_annee').change(function()
               {
                  alert("here");
```

I think I did all I had to do, but the trigger doesn't work.

Any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to *trigger* the `change` even before you have attached the `change` handler.

You should instead do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // bind the change handler
   $('#sel_annee').change(function() {
      ...
   });

   // now trigger it
   $('#sel_annee').trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Great, it works great ! unfortunately, I cannot give you an extra point, I don't have enough point to do that.  Have an excellent W.E.

Comment: @beegees - Thats not a problem. Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your document ready handler code you are attaching change handler first and then triggering change event.

Everything is perfect in your code and the only thing I think can go wrong is trying to trigger the event before attaching a function to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('#sel_annee').change(function(){
    alert('changed');
    });
    $('#sel_annee').trigger("change");
});
```